# Vagrant built VM is not working. mrt: command not found

Tags: meteor, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

I am following the instructions in a Tutorial for running Meteor in Windows
**https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5855677**

Everything was fine until when the VM booted up.

I'm stuck on step 9 on the instructions list.

Here's a link to the image of what I was doing in my command line from step 6.

**http://i1316.photobucket.com/albums/t606/redber2009/mrtcommandnotfound_zps3bc19e68.png**

How do you address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong right there. After you run `vagrant up` find the line `Forwarding ports...`. It should show port 22 and port 3000. I recommend you re-doing from the beginning in another folder. If you want to record it and post to youtube it would be easier to see what's happnening too. Use [Screen-O-Matic](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/) for easy recording and sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that step 5 did not do the job properly, i.e., running the "meteor.sh" install script.

Are you sure you downloaded the script and placed it in the right directory (as explained in the requirements)? Can you check it ran correctly (try commands like "node --version" and "meteor --version" to check Node/Meteor are correctly installed)?

One thing for sure, Meteorite ("mrt") has not be installed on your Ubuntu VM.